# AjaxControlKit Calendar Selector with SSRS

Tags: asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, calendarextender

I've noticed that the items in the calendar date selection dropdown in the AjaxControlKit are not available if the SSRS ASP.Net report viewer control is directly beneath it.

I had to add subsequent HTML/line spacing below it to give me the ability to select the rest of the lower dates in the control.

To solve this, I added a few more blank lines of HTML and that solved the problem.

However, this is a sub-optimal solution, as I have a SSRS report that should sit right underneath the selectors, and added unused vertical white-space is just wrong.

Setting the report viewer control to visible=false and swapping that on button-press is also not a good option, as you shouldn't have to clear the report area to select more dates.

Has anyone encountered this, and if so, what is the solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, I added a few more blank lines of HTML and that solved the problem.